# Single letter of Adobe Edge Font Didat Gothic rendering incorrectly on iPhone

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, iphone

I recently upgraded to Dreamweaver CC and tried using the Adobe Edge Font integration. It was simple enough to use and the font seemed to be working correct on my website. However, when I got around to testing the site on my iPhone, I ran into an odd problem. The letter 'W', both capitalized and lowercase, renders incorrectly. See image below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCRy9.png

So I went ahead and created a basic jsfiddle with the alphabet displayed in varying sizes. An example of the css is below along with the fiddle link.

http://jsfiddle.net/B2GMz/2/

```
h1 {
font-family: didact-gothic;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 6em;
}
</style>
<script src="//use.edgefonts.net/didact-gothic.js"></script>
```

When I view the page in Firefox on my desktop all the letters render correctly at all sizes. When I view the page in Safari on my iPhone, all the 'W' letters are rendered incorrectly at all sizes. What is even more odd is that after creating this fiddle I tested it out in Chrome and it renders correctly at the smaller sizes and incorrectly with the larger ones. To be more precise, 4em and above displays incorrectly.

I have searched online but have only found reasons why an entire font might not render. Hopefully there is someone out there that can help explain why this single letter decides to render correctly in some situations and incorrectly in others. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Here's an interesting thing (see [**http://typecast.com/preview/google/Didact%20Gothic**](http://typecast.com/preview/google/Didact%20Gothic)...there is no letter W in the character set listed. Odd...no?

Comment: That makes this even more odd. If that is the case how is the example text displaying the W characters? Interesting find.

Comment: It could be that, in some way, they are constructing the "W" fron two "V" characters. "W" certainly appears in the character set in the [**Character Set**](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Didact+Gothic). You could try contacting the [**developer**](https://plus.google.com/113574588462430984234/about)